# php code to fix canonical issue with joomla

Tags: php, function, if-statement, joomla, canonical-link

as we all know joomla has some pretty big issues with canonical problems, and not really a way of dealing with this problem... i've written a code that checks for the url and adds the rel= canonical link...

the code goes something like this:

```
<?php 
$canonicalLink =  "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 
if ($canonicalLink == 'http://domain.edu.au/index.php')
echo '<link rel="canonical" href="http://domain.edu.au/">';
if ($canonicalLink == 'http://domain.edu.au/?view=featured')
echo '<link rel="canonical" href="http://domain.edu.au/">';
?>
```

that works but my problem is:

i have too many pages on my website, and this if statement is going to be insanely huge

is there a way to convert this in to a function? that will read the urls from a list?

something like:

```
list:

http://domain.edu.au/?view=featured | http://domain.edu.au/
http://domain.edu.au/?view=contact | http://domain.edu.au/contact-us
http://domain.edu.au/?view=about | http://domain.edu.au/about-us
http://domain.edu.au/category-a/subcategory-a | http://domain.edu.au/category-main/subcategory-main
```

function:

```
function (a | b){
if (a)
echo 'b'
}
```

and make this run on a loop trough all the list on load...

does this make sense? or am i completelly off here?

cheers, dan

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
//populate $list with the end of the actual uri as the key
//and what you want the actual uri to be as the value
$list = array(
  '/index.php'=>'',
  '/?view=featured'=>'',
  '/?view=contact'=>'contact-us',
  '/?view=about'=>'about-us',
  '/category-a/subcategory-a'=>'category-main/subcategory-main'
);

echo '<link rel="canonical" href="http://domain.edu.au/'.$list[$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]].'">';
```

This makes it so you don't have to do any `if` logic. It becomes a straight lookup value.

Comment: sorry i think i forgot to mention i put that code on the index.php file of the template so this code will run on every page of the, site, thats why i need the if statement there to check what page we are on... and place the correct canonical link on the page.

Comment: @dan - This code would check what page you are on because of the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` portion. Try using this code and let me know what happens.

Comment: no didn't work all i'm getting is the following link on every page

<link rel="canonical" href="http://domain.edu.au/".$list[$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]]>

Comment: @dan - I'll help you debug your code. Meet me in [the discussion room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25263/discussion-between-aust-and-dan)